# Trigger onUpdate action in OctoberCMS

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I have a form in OctoberCMS backend and I want to make a javascript trigger that will be fired when the user save the form so I can manipulate the form fields.

The official documentations of [OctoberCMS Docs](https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/javascript-api) is not saying anything about it.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it was in the Documentations of [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/javascript-api):

> Executes JavaScript code when the ajaxUpdate event is triggered on an element.

```
$('.calcresult').on('ajaxUpdate', function() {
    console.log('Updated!');
});
```